# Running for loop with two variables?

Tags: scripting

How can I run **for loop** with `two variables` or in other words is it acceptable to do that? I will clarify my question by the following example:

I have a list of letters included in a text file "names.txt" and I have numbers included in text file "numbers.txt" each number in "numbers.txt" is equal to letter in "names.txt" (row by row) I want to create folders has the names in names.txt + the numbers in numbers.txt

```
names.txt       numbers.txt         output_folder name
A               1                   A1
B               2                   B2
C               3                   C3
D               4                   D4
E               5                   E5
```

to create folders has the names included in names.text I can use the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
in=/in/on/an
out=/ss/tt/nn
for i in $(cat $in/names.txt); do
 mkdir ${in}/${i}
done
```

How can I add a second variable to a for loop i.e in the previous code we have the variable i is belonging to the names.txt how can I add variable b belonging to numbers.txt?

Answer (score 0):

If that's really all you need, you can just do

```
mkdir $(paste letters.txt numbers.txt | tr -d '\t')
```

That will create the directories for you. As for the general case in bash, this is usually done in a similar way:

```
paste letters.txt numbers.txt | while read let num; do 
    mkdir "${let}${num}" 
done
```

To answer your specific question, you can't run a `for` loop with more than one variable in bash but there are usually ways around it as you can see. The closest you can get is using arrays. For example:

```
let=( $(cat letters.txt) )
num=( $(cat numbers.txt) )
for((i=0;i<${#let[@]};i++)); do 
    mkdir "${let[$i]}${num[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer. Kindly do you know any other ways to do loop for two variables

Comment: @dr.green it's not possible in bash. The workaround is using arrays, see update. Normally, if you need to combine variables you use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: Please can you explain the for .. do line of the code. Thanks

Comment: @dr.green see [here](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/working-with-arrays-in-bash-scripting.html). That construct means "for every value of $i from 0 to the number of elements in the array $let" (that's what `${#let[@]}` is). It is just a way to iterate over the elements in an array.

Comment: Cool! this is great. Many thousands of thanks